# Accessing object based on key provided

Tags: javascript

I have the following object and I want to access `contact:[object]` based on `id: '77f97928d4e796d'` which is the key. How do I do that?

```
[
    { contact: [Object],
          id: '77f97928d4e796d',
          createdDate: Thu Dec 29 2016 16:58:13 GMT+0530 (IST),
          name: 'Test',
          profileData: '' 
    },
    { contact: [Object],
        id: '77f97928d4e7944',
        createdDate: Thu Dec 29 2016 17:04:13 GMT+0530 (IST),
        name: 'Test2',
        profileData: '' 
    }
]
```

Comment: If you only have one object, what is the`id` used for? Also how is that object even stored? (You already know the key is `contact`, so where is the problem here?)

Comment: It looks like you copied that from the console? Did you try `contact.id`?

Comment: are you asking finding from array of such objects?

Comment: Be clear what you want to do?

Comment: @LonelyPlanet Yes there are array of objects with unique id's

Comment: @UnholySheep I have array of objects with unique id's for each of them. I just posted one in the question

Comment: @UnholySheep I am updating the values inside contact object based on id key provided. First I need to get hold of contact object based on id so that I can update the values inside contact object

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1 = [{ contact: [Object],
    id: '77f97928d4e796d',
    createdDate: Thu Dec 29 2016 16:37:21 GMT+0530 (IST),
    name: 'Test',
    profileData: '' 
}, { contact: [Object],
    id: '888fghwtw678299s',
    createdDate: Thu Dec 29 2016 16:37:21 GMT+0530 (IST),
    name: 'Test',
    profileData: '' 
}]
```

I am assuming you have multiple objects in array. You can just loop through the array and check for the id.

```
var providedKey = '77f97928d4e796d';
var myContact = null;
for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    if(arr1[i].id == providedKey){
        myContact = arr1[i].contact;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now you will have contact object in myContact variable.

Comment: Typo: `myObj` should be `myContact` (in the `if` inside the loop)

Comment: Also `arr[i]` should be `arr1[i]` and `arr1++` should be `i++`

Comment: Also you should add [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as a suggested alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.find` method:

```js
var array = [{ contact: [Object],
id: '77f97928d4e796d',
createdDate: 'Thu Dec 29 2016 16:58:13 GMT+0530 (IST)',
name: 'Test',
profileData: '' 
},
{ contact: [Object],
id: '77f97928d4e7944',
createdDate: 'Thu Dec 29 2016 17:04:13 GMT+0530 (IST)',
name: 'Test2',
profileData: '' 
}];

//Change the id string for the id you looking for
console.log(array.find(obj => obj.id == '77f97928d4e7944'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your array of object & if the Id matches with the current object, get the contact object.